# I am working on making an RPG Game with an end of the world storyline

Tags: weapons, skills, lore

I am working on making an RPG Game with an end of the world storyline, I want it to be like a huge asteroid is coming to hit earth. I got inspiration from an [asteroid map damage simulator](https://asteroidcollision.herokuapp.com/) website, you can visit it and input the max option if you want to see what I mean. I want my RPG game to be about having to survive the fallout but I am unsure of how to make a system in which it is fun (btw its an indie game). I've got the basics down, but I am unsure how to make the game more RPG'y. Like should it be round based or what? Was looking on this website https://forums.rpgmakerweb.com/index.php?threads/100-free-to-use-game-ideas-storyline-concepts.20786/ but I couldn't find anything that resonated with me. I also want to include weapons and combat.

Simple Question: Ideas for a game that includes the end of humanity and combat

thanks

(english not my first language sry)

Comment: Hi @Paul McBurney This is a question that is more suited for a forum. If you look at the beginning chapters of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* for D&D 5e, you will find helpful information about World building. There are 3rd party guidelines as well such as those published by Kobold Press. Have fun in your creation.

Comment: Please note that we curate [a list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970) that may help, including Our Very Own [chat]. You'll need 20 rep to participate there--I've thrown you an upvote, which gets you halfway there!

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate that!